# How to add SwipeRefreshLayout functionality to MaterialDrawer

Tags: android, materialdrawer

I want to add a pull-to-refresh functionality to the drawer items of a [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/) instance. Usually one would do this via the support libs [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) that already provides this functionality, but I couldn't find a nice way to integrate this into MaterialDrawer.

There is a builder option called `withDrawerLayout`, but this function expects a layout that actually has a DrawerLayout as its root element - this obviously won't help in my case.

Does anyone have an example or an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Do you also have a Header in your Drawer? You have to remember that the SwipeRefreshLayout would be the full height of the drawer and show the reloading on top.

Comment: Yup, this is a compromise that I expected and I'm willing to accept - actually, the refresh mechanism won't only refresh the menu items but also other stuff like the header image and app colors, so it isn't that wrong to pull down the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with versions lower than 5.1.2 of the MaterialDrawer

For your use case I have implemented a change which allows you to overwrite the `material_drawer_recycler_view.xml` layout, and to have a an additional view around it.

So to get the `SwipeRefreshLayout` do the following:

1. update to the **MaterialDrawer** v5.1.2
2. create a layout called `material_drawer_recycler_view.xml` in your project
3. add the `SwipeRefreshLayout`

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/material_drawer_recycler_view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:scrollbars="vertical" />
   ```
4. access the `SwipeRefreshLayout`

   SwipeRefreshLayout srl = (SwipeRefreshLayout) result.getSlider().findViewById(R.id.material_drawer_swipe_refresh);

Now you are able to use it as any other `SwipeRefreshLayout`

Comment: Mike, thank you! Didn't want to abuse the issue tracker for a question again, didn't expect such a fast solution here on StackOverflow :) Won't be able to implement this until next month due to holidays, but this is right next on my todo list.

Comment: Ok great ;). No problem. You were lucky I checked the "materialdrawer" tag ;)